# Mysql Select count with geospatial ST_Contains is very slow with multiple rows

Tags: mysql, innodb, geospatial

I have a mysql query to get all places count from an area. If I query for only one id it's really quick, if I query for two ids or more then it's really slow.

Areas.geometry and Places.location are SPATIAL indexes.

There is only 3 rows ( all have complex geometry. The row 3 is the more complex ) in areas table  and 3000 rows in stores. I build up a demo sql file to import if you want to test : [geospatial-exemple.sql](https://www.dropbox.com/s/haohbmccro2vizp/geospatial-exemple.sql?dl=1)

Some exemple :

This query is running in 260ms :

```
    select  a.name, 
            (
            SELECT  count(*)
                FROM  places p
                WHERE  ST_Contains(a.geometry,p.location)
            ) as places_count
        FROM  areas a
        WHERE  a.id in (1)
```

[image]

---

This query is running in 320ms :

```
    select  a.name, 
            (
            SELECT  count(*)
                FROM  places p
                WHERE  ST_Contains(a.geometry,p.location)
            ) as places_count
        FROM  areas a
        WHERE  a.id in (3)
```

[image]

---

This query is running in **50s** :

```
    select  a.name, 
            (
            SELECT  count(*)
                FROM  places p
                WHERE  ST_Contains(a.geometry,p.location)
            ) as places_count
        FROM  areas a
        WHERE  a.id in (1,3)
```

[image]

---

I also tried to hardcode the areas.geometry in the query with the more complex MULTIPOLYGON

This query is running in 380ms :

```
    select  a.name, 
            (
            SELECT  count(*)
                FROM  places p
                WHERE  ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromText("MULTIPOLYGON((...))",
                                    4326,
                                    'axis-order=long-lat'),p.location)
            ) as places_count
        FROM  areas a
        WHERE  a.id in (1,3)
```

[image]

---

So clearly it's faster to run multiple queries than only one and wait for a minutes. If somebody know if it's a mysql bug or if there is another way to do that ?
Working with Join query give the same results.

Comment: I tried with one city and it's fast. if I had one more city it's very slow. I could of course increment the count directly in a column, but I don't get why it's not working. Looks like a bug to me. I will update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [John Powells answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25446381/6248528), there is an undocumented limitation for spatial indexes:

> For the Contains and Intersects functions to work properly, and for the index to be used, you need to have one of the geometries be a constant. This doesn't appear to be documented, although all the examples you will see with MySQL with Intersects/Contains work this way.

So running multiple queries with one area each would indeed be faster.

If you have the permissions to create functions, you can however use a workaround by running your subquery in a function, where `areas.geometry` will now act as a constant parameter for `ST_Contains()`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_getplacescount(_targetarea GEOMETRY) 
RETURNS INT READS SQL DATA
RETURN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM places p WHERE ST_Contains(_targetarea, p.location));
```

Now

```
SELECT a.name, fn_getplacescount(a.geometry) AS places_count 
FROM areas a WHERE a.id in (1,3);
```

would be similar to running each area separately, and should have a similar execution time as using two separate queries.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation !  I never heard about sql functions, but just tried it on the server and it's working quick ! Thanks, it will be cleaner in my code.

Comment: Just to clarify: while functions are nice, worth to know about and can make your code look cleaner/shorter, a usage like here is just as a workaround! In almost every other case, a subquery is faster, more flexible and the right choice. (This is just a disclaimer to prevent that you start to write your queries using functions now - in contrast to normal programming languages, splitting code into many small functions (or classes/...) is not the way to go for sql! If you meant it's cleaner than writing code to run 100 separate queries to speed up this specific problem: then yes.)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to express it as a join and see if MySQL run it faster. Not sure if MySQL has optimized spatial join, but it would be faster in the databases I worked with.

Something like this (I did not check the syntax):

```sql
SELECT areas.name, count(*) as places_count
FROM places p JOIN areas a
ON ST_Contains(a.geometry, p.location)
WHERE a.type = "city"
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your participation, but I tried it and it's the same problem. Running super fast if I have only one row with type='city' and super slow if I have more than on rows with type city. I will try to update my question with more accurate details.